# extension file making image flip upside down (swift3)

Tags: swift3, rotation, imageview, double, extension-methods

The following extension file generates my image upside down. All i need to do is flip my image by 180 degrees.

```
   case .landscapeLeft:

        var transform: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: self.size.width, y: self.size.height)
        transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi/2))


        guard let cgImage = self.cgImage, let colorSpace = cgImage.colorSpace, let context: CGContext = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(self.size.width), height: Int(self.size.height), bitsPerComponent: cgImage.bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: 0, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue) else { return self }
        context.concatenate(transform)
        context.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height))
        guard let transformed = context.makeImage() else { return self }
        return UIImage(cgImage: transformed)


        return imageResult!
```

I have tried to use 3 * Double.pi / 2 but that makes no image appear on the image view. The only math formula that gets a image on the image view is double.pi / 2 for my code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code rotates the image about the origin of the image which happens to be the top left hand corner. You need to translate the origin to be the centre of the image before applying the rotation and then after translate the origin back to the top left corner. If you replace your transform construction with the following it should work

```
    var transform: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    transform = transform.translatedBy(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
    transform = transform.rotated(by: angle)
    transform = transform.translatedBy(x: -self.size.width/2, y: -self.size.height/2)
```